# Как реализовано кэширование запросов к mysql на сервере?

Tags: php, кэширование, mysql

Здравствуйте.  Довожу до конца скрипт админки сайта. В базе данных есть таблица connection, в которой содержаться "отзывы", "пожелания" и "вопросы" пользователей. Админу должно выводиться общее количество этих постов, сгруппированных по вышеуказанным категориям, а также конкретное количество непрочитанных.

Естественно, это ресурсоемкий запрос к mysql. Вопрос: **кешируются ли такие запросы автоматически на сервере**? Или при каждом обновлении страницы снова и снова будет происходить один и тот же запрос к таблице connection?

Или в простейшем случае я должен использовать некий файл, в который помещаются результаты запроса, а далее, если время его жизни, например, более часа, обновлять его?

Comment: Ну если запрос одинаков то да работает query cache просто поиграйтесь с параметрами этого кэша

Comment: Можно и с файлом работать, но зачем вам тогда БД, помещайте результаты запросов в бд в отдельную таблицу, както разбейте её по датам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если поле категорий с индексом, то операция группировки не очень ресурсоемкая.

В MySQL [есть](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Query_Cache.html) внутреннее кеширование результатов выполнения SELECT-запросов.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте memcached.

Comment: И сколько надо памяти дополнительно для неё? Много.

Comment: это смотря что вы в него запихаете. Если в него ложить число (общее количество постов) то будет занимать не так уж и много даже если этих чисел будт там несколько тысяч. Память нынче стоит копейки а доступ к такому кешу на порядок выше чем к базе или к файлу на диске.